# How to get two or more components to listen to eachother and turn off when others turn on

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have three components in my React app, all set to grey but can turn a different color when clicked, and the idea is to have the other components change back to grey whenever one of the components turns from grey to it's chosen color. Another way to phrase it is that I want only one components to show it's color at a time.

Here is the index.js for my page.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";
import Redlight from "./Components/Redlight";
import Yellowlight from "./Components/Yellowlight";
import Greenlight from "./Components/Greenlight";

// probably add "isActive" line here? need to 
// figure out how to get the components to listen
// to eachother

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Redlight />
      <Yellowlight />
      <Greenlight />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

And here is one of the components. All the components are written the exact same way, so consider this one to count as all three besides the obvious differences of color.

```
import React from "react";

class Redlight extends React.Component {
  state = {
    className: "Offlight"
  };

  handleClick = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("The red light was clicked.");
    const currentState = this.state.className;
    this.setState({
      className: !currentState
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        className={this.state.className ? "Offlight" : "Redlight"}
        onClick={this.handleClick}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default Redlight;
```

So far all the components show up and change color on click, but it's the matter of getting them all to listen to each other that is really hanging me up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving your state to your root component, which in your case is App, then make App stateful and Redlight, Bluelight, and Greenlight stateless.

If you turn your App component into a stateful component, you can pass the state of the lights down to the children component while at the same time you can manage their states in the parent's component level.

For example, for your App.js, do something like:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Redlight from "./Redlight";
import Yellowlight from "./Yellowlight";
import Greenlight from "./Greenlight";
import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    red: "Offlight",
    yellow: "Offlight",
    green: "Offlight"
  };

  clickHandler = (light, e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("The " + light + " light was clicked.");
    const currentState = this.state[light];

    const newState = {
      red: "Offlight",
      yellow: "Offlight",
      green: "Offlight"
    };

    this.setState({
      ...newState,
      [light]: !currentState
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Redlight light={this.state.red} clicked={this.clickHandler} />
        <Yellowlight light={this.state.yellow} clicked={this.clickHandler} />
        <Greenlight light={this.state.green} clicked={this.clickHandler} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

If you see, the state in the parent is controlling the class name for the lights, and the clickHandler turns all of them off, them turns the clicked one on.

Your children components can be cleaner, like this:

Yellowlight.js

```js
import React from "react";

class Yellowlight extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div
        className={this.props.light ? "Offlight" : "Yellowlight"}
        onClick={(e) => this.props.clicked('yellow', e)}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default Yellowlight;
```

Redlight.js

```js
import React from "react";

class Redlight extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div
        className={this.props.light ? "Offlight" : "Redlight"}
        onClick={(e) => this.props.clicked('red', e)}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default Redlight;
```

Greenlight.js:

```js
import React from "react";

class Greenlight extends React.Component {
   render() {
    return (
      <div
        className={this.props.light ? "Offlight" : "Greenlight"}
        onClick={(e) => this.props.clicked('green', e)}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default Greenlight;
```

You can check the final code in this sandbox where I tried to replicate your problem: https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-haibt-i4nck

[image: Edit friendly-haibt-i4nck]

Comment: This seems to work, but it doesn't apply the CSS to each light when rendered. It just renders the text on screen as "GreenLight: GreenLight" which tells me that it's already trying to render itself turned on?

Comment: Can you share your styles.css, so I can have a better idea of what you're trying to set up? I'm setting up a copy of your project here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandbox-4u4pv

Comment: Sure, here you go:
```.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.Offlight {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.Redlight {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.Yellowlight {
  background-color: Yellow;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.Greenlight {
  background-color: Green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}```

Comment: Hey, Patrick, I updated the answer and I got to the result you wanted by moving the states from the children components to the parent component. It's working here: https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-haibt-i4nck

Comment: Just plugged the code into my version of the activity and it works like a charm! Looks like I have a lot to learn about how to properly utilize parent/child relationships in React, so thank you so much for helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are looking for something like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-57734290-v3bv2?fontsize=14)

What you need, is to lift up the state in order to hold the selected color/light into it. For this example, I'm using the [state hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) instead of the class component approach. I've also created one `<Light />` component as they share the same logic.

You can find inline comments of what is going on for each of the steps.

Let me know if you find any trouble reading or implementing it.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to [lift the state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) to a common ancestor. You can create a common ancestor to host the information that all 3 light components need. You can pass a boolean `isLightOn` to tell the component to switch on or off. You will also pass an event handler to allow a light component to set the light color.

```
  const LightContainer = () => {
  const [lightColor, setLightColor] = useState('');
  const RED_COLOR = 'RED';
  const YELLOW_COLOR = 'YELLOW';
  const GREEN_COLOR = 'GREEN';
  return (
    <div>
      <Light className="Redlight" isLightOn={lightColor === RED_COLOR} onLightSwitch={() => { setLightColor(RED_COLOR); }} />
      <Light className="Yellowlight" isLightOn={lightColor === YELLOW_COLOR} onLightSwitch={() => { setLightColor(YELLOW_COLOR); }} />
      <Light className="Greenlight" isLightOn={lightColor === GREEN_COLOR} onLightSwitch={() => { setLightColor(GREEN_COLOR); }} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

On your light components, we can also make it more generic since we move most of the logic to the parent component.

```
const Light = ({ isLightOn, onLightSwitch, className }) => {
  return (
    <div
      className={isLightOn ? 'Offlight' : className}
      onClick={onLightSwitch}
    />
  );
};
```